# SQL Server XML output with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm faced with a little question on xml output.

[I need to get xml structure like this:](http://i50.tinypic.com/10ydimq.png)

and here is my procedure, it'll list all the employees and some of their personal info
based on input.

```
CREATE PROC getDeptEmployees(@deptList varchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @Query varchar(600)

SET @Query = '
SELECT department.DEPARTMENT_ID [f_Department_ID], department.DEPARTMENT_NAME  [f_Department_name],
dp.Employee_id [f_Employee_ID], dp.First_name [f_First_Name], 
dp.Last_Name [f_Last_name], dp.Email [f_email], dp.Salary [f_salary]
FROM dbo.Employees dp 
JOIN DEPARTMENTS department 
ON dp.DEPARTMENT_ID = department.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE dp.Department_id IN (' + @deptList + ') 
for XML AUTO, ROOT(''table'')'

EXEC(@Query)    
END
GO
```

What I get is [here](http://i47.tinypic.com/ncjl28.png)
but I still can't figure out how to add the DPR node.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `FOR XML PATH` functionality in SQL Server 2005, and a correlated subquery - something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT 
    d.Department_ID AS '@f_Department_ID',
    d.Department_Name AS '@f_Department_name',
    (SELECT 
        e.BusinessEntityID AS '@f_Employee_ID',
        e.FirstName AS '@f_First_Name',
        e.LastName AS '@f_Last_name',
            e.Email AS '@f_email',
        e.Salary AS '@f_salary'
     FROM
        dbo.Employee e
     WHERE
        e.Department_ID = d.Department_ID
     FOR XML PATH('dp'), TYPE
    ) AS 'dpr' 
FROM 
    dbo.Department d 
WHERE 
    d.DepartmentID IN (.......) 
ORDER BY 
    d.DepartmentID
FOR XML PATH('department'), ROOT('table')
```

Basically, the innermost query creates the XML element for a single employee

```
<dp f_Employee_ID="6" f_First_Name="Jossef" f_Last_name="Goldberg" f_salary="998320692" />
```

Using this as a correlated subquery with an alias of `AS 'dpr'` then wraps the list of employees for a given department into a `<dpr>` tag:

```
<dpr>
  <dp f_Employee_ID="4" f_First_Name="Rob" f_Last_name="Walters" f_salary="112457891" />
  <dp f_Employee_ID="11" f_First_Name="Ovidiu" f_Last_name="Cracium" f_salary="974026903" />
  <dp f_Employee_ID="12" f_First_Name="Thierry" f_Last_name="D'Hers" f_salary="480168528" />
  <dp f_Employee_ID="13" f_First_Name="Janice" f_Last_name="Galvin" f_salary="486228782" />
</dpr>
```

You then add this XML fragment to the outer most `SELECT` which creates the `<department>` node, and you should get the desired output.

For more info on `FOR XML PATH` see:

- [MSDN documentation in the SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx)
- [FOR XML PATH - A New Mode in FOR XML with SQL Server 2005](http://geekswithblogs.net/chavansachinr/archive/2007/04/30/112132.aspx)
- [SQL SERVER – Simple Example of Creating XML File Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Now things are much more understandable.

Comment: @Caerus: yes, the `FOR XML PATH` mode is a big and very helpful addition to SQL Server's XML support!